# Problem when doing pre-whitening before ccf analysis

Tags: r, time-series

I have following R code which does not work when trying to pre-whiten other series by the model generated for the other series.

```
-- Libraries;  
library(forecast);  
library(TSA);  
library(xts); 

-- Read from csv;  
....    

-- Do transforms;  

Power=xts(data1[2],seq(from=as.Date("2011-01-01"), to=as.Date("2013-09-18"),by="day"),frequency=7);   
Temp=xts(data2[1],seq(from=as.Date("2011-01-01"), to=as.Date("2013-09-18"),by="day"),frequency=7);   

-- Prewhiten for CCF;

mod1=Arima(Temp,order=c(2,0,1),seasonal=list(order=c(1,1,1)));  

Box.test(mod1$residuals,lag=365,type=c("Ljung-Box"));  

x_series=mod1$residuals;  

y_filtered=residuals(Arima(Power,model=mod1));
```

Last Part does not work since I get error:

```
Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  : 
  wrong length for 'fixed'
```

What goes wrong here?

Comment: As long as you have library(TSA), just use the prewhiten() function from that package.
Why make life difficult??

Comment: @user242509 thanks for the hint concerning prewhiten()-function. Unfortunately it provided me following error prewhiten(Temp,Power,x.model=mod1):Error in na.omit.ts(as.ts(x)) : all times contain an NA. If I put only prewhiten(Temp,Power) it will do prewhitening using AR(p) model for both series, estimated by the Temp series. Results seem to be reasonable in CCF plot, but still I would like to be able to do this by ARIMA model and not just AR(p) model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arima` and `stats::arima` both require `ts` objects. The error is caused by `xts` objects being used. Try this instead:

```
Power <- ts(data1[2], frequency=7)
Temp <- ts(data2[1], frequency=7)
mod1 <- Arima(Temp,order=c(2,0,1),seasonal=c(1,1,1))
Box.test(residuals(mod1),lag=365,type=c("Ljung-Box"))
x_series <- residuals(mod1)
y_filtered <- residuals(Arima(Power,model=mod1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! This works but I do not see time index in the same way as before. Could you tell why CCF-analysis produces quite similar results with these comparisons: ccf(x_series,y_series,lag=365) and prewhiten(Temp,Power)? Other uses arima model and other AR(p)..